# Every time I connect ADE measuring chip , it blows up

Tags: current-measurement, shunt

**My current system:-**

I'm working on a electricity metering system ,

I'm using [shunt resistor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunt_%28electrical%29#Current_measurement_techniques) configured in high side mode (a current sensor ) ,

I'm also using [ADE7755](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/ADE7755.pdf) measuring chip ,

A schematic of the current circuit :-

[image]

A higher resolution schematic [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWYla.png)

**The problem:-**
When connecting the circuit as shown in the above schematic , R1, R2 , R3 & R4 blow up with some fire .

This isn't the first time happens , it happened before 3 times .

My initial guess it's that Analog & Digital ground are connected some how ..

I'm ready for any questions to clear the problem , thanks .

***UPDATE#1 :-***

I connected the PIN AGND in ADE 7755 chip to the Digital ground

Comment: What's the idea of posting an 11 Mpixel BMP image for a *schematic*? If you would use the PNG format it would be less than 100 kB, so you wouldn't need the ZIP. And you can easily scale it down by 75 %, without any concessions to readability. I edited the link.

Comment: @stevenvh for ppl who need zoom (like me :D ) 
thanks =)

Comment: I think you can do other things for better readability than going to huge image sizes. For instance there's a line running through the values of R3 and R4. Wait until [Olin](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/28251/rules-and-guidelines-for-drawing-good-schematics) sees this :-).

Answer (score 3):

If you look closely at the datasheet, you'll see that it plainly says the maximum signal you can apply to the amplifier inputs with respect to analog ground is +/- 1V (+/- 6V over voltage tolerance).

Your high-side current transducer is going to put a lot more common-mode stress than that on those pins, hence the blow-ups.

Consider a low-side sensor or an isolated transducer like a current transformer that can be referenced to the IC return.

Be safe - playing with the mains can be lethal. (I'm glad to see a fuse in your circuit!)